# PHP Looping....need some advice

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$q1 = $_POST["q1"];
$q2 = $_POST["q2"];
$q3 = $_POST["q3"];
$q4 = $_POST["q4"];
$q5 = $_POST["q5"];
$q6 = $_POST["q6"];
$q7 = $_POST["q7"];
$q8 = $_POST["q8"];
```

At the moment, this is hard coded and I need to manually change it each time, I'd like to use variables instead so that it's not a manual process.

Is it a case of using a loop, while or foreach?

If I had the the information $q and q in an array would that help?

Thanks,

Homer.

Comment: Just as a sidenote, you could also change your post values to send as `name="q[1]"` through to `name="q[8]"`, then you could work with that data as a distinct array, directly, by using `$_POST['q']`. // Edit: Gordon beat me to it. XD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider adjusting your forms to use Array notation, e.g.

```
<ul>
    <li><input name="q[]" /></li>
    <li><input name="q[]" /></li>
    <li><input name="q[]" /></li>
    <li><input name="q[]" /></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

This would make `$_POST['q']` contain an array with all input values given for 'q', which you can then easily iterate over with `foreach` like this:

```
foreach($_POST['q'] as $q) {
    // do something with $q
}
```

See http://www.johnrockefeller.net/html-input-forms-sending-in-an-array-in-php/

Comment: you can also explicity set the array keys if they refer to specific items/questions on the server, e.g. `name="q[4]"`, etc'.

Comment: @Gordon - thanks for that but I can't make use of the "q[]" feature you mention without changing the whole approach. I already have the information in an array.

Comment: @Homer no problem. Only you can decide if it makes sense for your app.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is the time for a loop. You can use foreach or while, it does not really matter.

```
$i = 1; 
$q = array(); 
while($i < 9) {
    $q[$i] = $_POST["q" . $i];
    $i += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1.

```
$keys = array('q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q5', 'q9');
$q = array();
foreach ( $keys as $key ) {

  $q[$key] = isset($_POST[$key]) ? $_POST[$key] : null;
}
```

2.

```
$keys = array('q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q5', 'q9');
foreach ( $keys as $key ) {
  $$key = isset($_POST[$key]) ? $_POST[$key] : null;
}
// in output you will have variables called $q1, $q2, $q3, ...
```

3.

```
$amount = 8;
$q = array();
for ( $i = 1; $i <= $amount; ++$i ) {
  $q[$i] = isset($_POST['q' . $i]) ? $_POST['q' . $i] : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, and it's been a while since I last used PHP:

```
$q = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; ++$i)
    $q[$i] = $_POST["q" . $i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, in case if it's ok with you to save POST data to another array:

```
// Random POST array
$_POST["q1"] = 1;
$_POST["q2"] = 2;
$_POST["q3"] = 3;
$_POST["q4"] = 4;
$_POST["q5"] = 5;
$_POST["q6"] = 6;
$_POST["q7"] = 7;
$_POST["q8"] = 8;

$array = Array( );

foreach ( $_POST as $value ) {
    $array[ ] = $value;
}
```

In case you want to save POST data into more specific variables, you'll have to use bit more complex piece of code. Can edit my post if you want to see more options.

**Edit:**

If you wanted to work just with keys that start with `q` and end with number, you could use following code:

```
$array = Array( );

foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
    if ( preg_match( "/^[q]{1}\d$/", $key ) ) {
        $array[ ] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: He may have other $_POST variables that he does not want to load in the array.